# Does realloc() invalidate all pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

Note, this question is not asking if `realloc()` invalidates pointers within the original block, but if it invalidates all the other pointers.

I am a bit confused about the nature of `realloc()`, specifically if it moves any other memory.

For example:

```
void* ptr1 = malloc(2);
void* ptr2 = malloc(2);
....
ptr1 = realloc(ptr1, 3);
```

After this, can I guarantee that `ptr2` points to the same data it did before the `realloc()` call?

Comment: "_After this, can I guarantee that ptr2 points to the same data it did before the realloc() call?_" -- __Yes__

Comment: Why do you think this could be the case? How could one possibly use `realloc` for anything if it did that?

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure, I suppose you might keep track of how much the memory moved, and could shift other pointers if needed. Sounds ridiculous, I know, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: You are not allowed to **look** at an invalid pointer, much less adjust it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `ptr2` is unaffected by `realloc()`, it has no connection to `realloc()` call whatsoever(as per the current code).

However, FWIW, as per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) of `realloc()`, (emphasis mine)

> The realloc() function returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any kind of variable and **may be different from ptr,**

`ptr1` is likely to be changed.

That said,

```
 ptr1 = realloc(ptr1, 3);
```

style is very dangerous. In case `realloc()` fails,

> The realloc() function returns .... or NULL if the request fails

and

> If `realloc()` fails the original block is left untouched; it is not freed or moved.

but, as per your statement, in failure case the `NULL` return will overwrite the actual memory, losing the actual memory and creating memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

> After this, can I guarantee that ptr2 points to the same data it did
>   before the realloc() call?

Yes. `realloc` doesn't affect other pointers/memory allocations you did.

Note that the method of `realloc`:

```
ptr = realloc(ptr, ...);
```

is not safe if `realloc` fails. See [Does realloc overwrite old contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850749/does-realloc-overwrite-old-contents)

Answer (score 0):

`ptr2` is not affected by realloc of `ptr1`.

Answer (score 0):

If Memory is available behind the heap realloc allocates that. 
If not, It is like malloc a block of the new size, It memcpy your content there.