# C dynamically growing array with malloc

Tags: c

I tried to create dynamically growing array I did with realloc. I have example below but I do not understand how this code works by using malloc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int cnt = 0;
    double *numbers = NULL;
    double newnum;
    while (scanf("%lf", &newnum) == 1 && newnum != -1) {
        double *newarr = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * (cnt+1)); 
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
            newarr[i] = numbers[i]; 
        free(numbers); 
        numbers = newarr;
        numbers[cnt] = newarr; 
        ++cnt;
    }

    for (int i = cnt-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%f\n", numbers[i]);
    }

    free(numbers);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that `numbers[cnt] = newarr;` is supposed to be `numbers[cnt] = newnum;`

Comment: You might like to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 2):

`realloc()` is the same as `malloc()`, `memcpy()`, `free()` all in one function *(*)*.

The loop in your code effectively replaces `memcpy()`

```
        // memcpy(newarr, numbers, cnt * sizeof *newarr);
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i)
            newarr[i] = numbers[i];
```

---

<sup>*(*)* `realloc()` may be smart enough to avoid the `memcpy()` and `free()` and reuse memory.</sup>

---

> How can I implement this in my code?

It helps to encapsulate the pointer and the total/used elements in a structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct DynArray {
    double *data;
    size_t m; // total
    size_t n; // used
};

void growarray(struct DynArray *x) {
    size_t newsize = x->m * 13 / 8 + 1; // use phi aproximation 13/8
    double *newarr = realloc(x->data, newsize * sizeof *x->data);
    if (!newarr) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    fprintf(stderr, "INFO: realloc'ed with %d elements.\n", (int)newsize);
    x->data = newarr;
    x->m = newsize;
}

int main(void) {
    struct DynArray numbers = { 0 };
    double newnum;
    while (scanf("%lf", &newnum) == 1 && newnum != -1) {
        if (numbers.n == numbers.m) growarray(&numbers);
        numbers.data[numbers.n] = newnum;
        numbers.n++;
    }

    for (int i = numbers.n - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        printf("%f\n", numbers.data[i]);
    }

    free(numbers.data);

    return 0;
}
```

[See code running on ideone](https://ideone.com/1NkLmi) or [previous version without growarray function](https://ideone.com/y22Hso) or [previous version with cnt](https://ideone.com/rybKlo)

Comment: I understood. It seems it is better to use realloc.

Comment: Make sure you [use `realloc()` correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850749/does-realloc-overwrite-old-contents/3850798#3850798)

Comment: Also realize that memory allocation is a slow operation and you should instead use a x2, or better, golden ratio to double or ~x1.618 your array size respectively, when you do need more space, and not every single iteration...

Comment: @EmilBədrəddinli: nicely spotted!! `cnt` is a left over from the original code. It was replaced by `numbers.n`. It is safe to delete and I've edited my answer.

Comment: Clearly explained. Thanks